# Posting Messages to Chrome Extension from Angular

Tags: angular, google-chrome

I'm trying the post a message to my Chrome Extension from my Angular4 application, but the extension doesn't hear it. It works fine from a simple HTML page, though. So I know it's working on the extension side.  Is there something with Angular that is restricting it?

Below is my Code.

Sending the message (in Angular):

```
window.postMessage({ type: 'IsExtInstalled', text: '' }, '*');
```

Listening for the message (in Chrome Ext):

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "IsExtInstalled")) {
        console.log("extension is installed");
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your sendMessage usage with a simple angular4 app?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it - it was because I hadn't added the url where the angular was to the "content_scripts/matches" sections of the extension's manifest.json.